# Moving Body using force in Libgdx based off of touch input

Tags: java, android, vector, libgdx, physics

What I am trying to do is take in an inputted user touch down, convert the camera coordinates of the touch down to world coordinates, then create a vector to use in order to apply force to my body.
This is what I have for that:

```
    Vector3 worldPos = new Vector3(newX, newY, 0);
    GameScreen.gameCam.unproject(worldPos);

    newX = worldPos.x;
    newY = worldPos.y;

    Vector2 direction = new Vector2();

    direction.set((newX - xPos), (newY - yPos));
     if (newX <= xPos){
        direction.set((xPos - newX), (yPos - newY));
    }

    b2Body.applyForceToCenter(direction, true);
```

I know that this really isn't right at all as far as creating the vector goes, but the coordinates are being converted properly.

So my question is, how can I get an accurate vector, even in the negative direction, when I have both the world coordinates of the body and touch down?

I have tried doing some research to get a better understanding of all of this but I am having a bit of trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have on newX, newY screen touch coordinates and next change it to world coords you can get direction by subtraction touchWorldPos to currentObjectPos:

```
Vector3 worldPos = new Vector3(newX, newY, 0);
GameScreen.gameCam.unproject(worldPos);

newX = worldPos.x;
newY = worldPos.y;

Vector2 direction = new Vector2();
direction.set((newX - xPos), (newY - yPos));


b2Body.applyForceToCenter(direction, true);
```

without this if statement:

```
 if (newX <= xPos){
    direction.set((xPos - newX), (yPos - newY));
 }
```

in box2d this direction might have small values and you must muliply this one by some value like 100(mayby more)